# Event listeners on the IFrame with ExtJS4.1.2

Tags: iframe, extjs, extjs4

I am using 'uxiframe' component to load a separate application into a modal window (ExtJS4.1x). 
Cross domain issues clearly do not allow me to access any part of the IFrame contents. However same domain app's Document in the IFrame is accessible from the parent via `iframe.getDoc()`

The question is this: Is there a way for me to setup DOM listeners on the elements inside the IFrame from the parent modal window?

Thanks and a simple example would be appreciated.

**Update** Thanks to @lontiviero for a tip to get me started. Here is what I ended up with:

```
var bodyEl=Ext.get(iframe.getDoc().body);  //this gives me an Ext.dom.Element object 
bodyEl.on('click',
          function(event, el,opts){
             console.log("<p> clicked");
          },
          this, //scope
          {delegate:'p'} //options
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code i was able to attach an event to the iframe´s body element.

```
Ext.EventManager.on(iframe.contentDocument.body, 'mouseover', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Take a look at it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XApQU/

Comment: looks very promising, testing now.